# Textblock binding issues with converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to use the font icon in my TextMlock control to display specific icon.
For this, I use text block binded with some text which is converted through a converter to a specific symbol code. But instead of displaying that particular symbol the text block is displaying the symbol code without `&#` characters. Am I doing something wrong here?

Converter class:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var catagoryString = value?.ToString().Trim();
    var returnString = string.Empty;
    if (stringConditionOne)
    {
        return "&#xe1ef;";
    }
    if (strinConditionTwo)
    {
        return @"&#x1f516;";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Textblock binding:

```
<TextBlock
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="4"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
    FontSize="10"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Text="{Binding TextProperty, Converter={StaticResource stringToSymbolConvertor}}"
    TextAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of the code example? Unfortunately, it is more confusing than helpful to me. It doesnt even seem to be runnable.

Comment: @Jannik Its the famous empty string converter with anti-compilability-features of course. Anubhav should probably update the question, since he approved an edit by vantian, where the code was not only reformatted but also stripped of valuable information

Comment: @Jannik The basic purpose of this code is just to display a font icon in the text block which represent's state of the operation. i.e: display checking requirements.

Comment: @grek40 Unable to understand what you are trying to say. Sorry, my English is not that much strong to recognise what you said.

Comment: @grek40 Thanks Grek, not sure why he had deleted it, but it's fixed now :)

Comment: @Jannik yes, after writing the comment I realized that it would be much more useful to just fix this with an edit :). Anubhav: everything ok now, but someone had edited your post in a way, where your question could not be understood anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code behind use \u

```
"\ue1ef;"
```

Comment: Worth adding a link to : [Unicode character escape sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) MSDN Page.